# New to programming. Need help adjusting code to allow for undetermined number of students

Tags: c

Need help adjusting code to allow for undetermined number of students. Tried to modify with help I received last week, but it seems like I am not doing it correctly.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main ()
    {
      /* variable definition: */
      char StudentName[100];
      float ExamValue, Sum, Avg;
      int students,exams;
       // Loop through 5 Students
      for (students=0; students <5 ; students++) 
      {
         // reset Sum to 0
         Sum =0.0;  
         printf("Enter Student Name \n");
         scanf("%s", StudentName);   
         // Nested Loop for Exams
        for (exams=0; exams < 3; exams++)
        {
            printf ("Enter exam grade: \n");
            scanf("%f", &ExamValue);
            Sum += ExamValue;
        }   
        Avg = Sum/3.0;
        printf( "Average for %s is %f\n",StudentName,Avg);
      }
      return 0;
      }
```

Not sure how I need to go about changing the code. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: If you are new to programming, I recommend you use a text book, not come here asking random questions; there is a trivial answer to your question (if I understand it correctly), but spoon-feeding you answers is not going to help you develop.

Comment: Firstly, you need to be clear on the requirements - how is "no more students to input" indicated? That should be specified by your assignment/task requirements. e.g. a special input that indicates the end or there is a number input first to indicate the number of students.

Comment: Kaylum, not sure how to answer your question. The task is to modify the code to be able to input an undetermined number of students.

Comment: Ken, I made the mistake of starting a course for programming without prior knowledge of programming. The text book I have covers problem solving and algorithm design, but not basic programming

Comment: Well, then `while(1)` will achieve reading an indefinete number of students. Right?

Comment: It does, but when I input after the for "(students=0; students <5 ; students++)", the output continues to loop, without providing a calculation

Comment: Have you learned about dynamic memory allocation (`malloc()`, `realloc()`, `free()`) yet?  If not, you've been set, or have set yourself a difficult task.  You'd do best to read about those — but you also need to have learned about pointers.  Without a knowledge of pointers and dynamic memory allocation, you can't handle a truly indefinite number of students — you might need 100, or 1,000, or 1,000,000 or even 100,000,000 entries in your array, which can be handled with dynamic memory allocation but not otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for the advice Jonathan. I haven't learned dynamic memory allocations yet.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand correctly, I understood you want to loop an undertemined amount of students.

I will assume you want to stop if certain keyword is added as a student name, let's say "quit".

Without changing your structure much, it would look like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h> 
#include <string.h>

int main (){
    char StudentName[100];
    float ExamValue, Sum, Avg;
    int students,exams;
    bool in = true;

    while (in) {
        Sum =0.0;

        printf("Enter Student Name \n");
        scanf("%s", StudentName);
        if( strcmp(StudentName, "Quit") == 0 || strcmp(StudentName, "quit") == 0){
            in = false;
            break;
        }


        for (exams=0; exams < 3; exams++){
            printf ("Enter exam grade: \n");
            scanf("%f", &ExamValue);
            Sum += ExamValue;
        }

        Avg = Sum/3.0;
        printf( "Average for %s is %f\n",StudentName,Avg);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @David C. Rankin - No-one _will run into problems on_ _second iteration due to the `'\n'` left in the input buffer by `scanf("%f", &ExamValue);`_, since that `'\n'` is transparently discarded by the following `scanf("%s", StudentName)`. If you are the downvoter, it would be fair towards the answerer to reconsider.

Comment: No, I'm not your downvoter. I rarely, if ever, downvote. Instead I always try and help and at most leave a comment. The numeric *conversion specifiers* do consume all leading whitespace, so `%f` will consume any newline left in the input buffer, but I would still caution against successive mixed character/numeric input simply due to the subtleties between which consume whitespaced, (e.g. `%[...]` compared to `%s`, etc.. I Hope you find your downvoter.